# WPF Converter unclear behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I'm trying to make a navigator, that shows a thumbnail of `ScrollViewer` `Content`. My application has work area, where I place objects and which I want to show in navigator:

```
<local:WorkArea x:Name="WorkArea" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Work area is a `UserControl`, which has this structure:

```
<UserControl>
     <ScrollViewer>
          <Canvas/>
     <ScrollViewer/>
<UserControl/>
```

My navigator is also a `UserControl`:

```
<local:Navigator DataContext="{Binding ElementName=WorkArea, Path=Content}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                 Width="250" Height="250" Margin="0,0,10,10" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

It's structure:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DbCreator.Navigator"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DbCreator"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Opacity="0.9"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:WorkAreaToNavigatorConverter x:Key="WorkAreaToNavigatorConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border BorderBrush="#757575" BorderThickness="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Width="{Binding ElementName=ViewBox, Path=ActualWidth}"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=ViewBox, Path=ActualHeight}">
    <Viewbox x:Name="ViewBox" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ActualWidth}"
             Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Grid Background="White">
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Content.ActualWidth}"
                       Height="{Binding Content.ActualHeight}"
                       Name="Thumbnail">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding Content, Converter={StaticResource WorkAreaToNavigatorConverter}}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Border Background="#20000000" x:Name="ViewPort" Cursor="SizeAll"
                    Width="{Binding ViewportWidth}" Height="{Binding ViewportHeight}"
                    MaxWidth="{Binding Content.ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{Binding Content.ActualHeight}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    MouseDown="Border_MouseDown"
                    MouseUp="Border_MouseUp"
                    MouseMove="Border_MouseMove">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding HorizontalOffset}" Y="{Binding VerticalOffset}"/>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Border>
```

So, I bind work area's content (`ScrollViewer`) to navigator's `DataContext`. `Rectangle` inside `Viewbox` represents thumbnail of work area's `Canvas`. I fill `Rectangle` with `VisualBrush`, which binds to work area's `Canvas`. Without converter I have this:

[image: Without converter]

I want to convert work area's `Canvas` to another `Canvas`, that doesn't have grid lines and contains rectangles instead of tables. So i wrote `WorkAreaToNavigatorConverter`:

```
public class WorkAreaToNavigatorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Canvas workAreaCanvas = value as Canvas;
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas()
        {
            Width = workAreaCanvas.ActualWidth,
            Height = workAreaCanvas.ActualHeight,
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
        };
        foreach (Table table in workAreaCanvas.Children.OfType<Table>())
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle()
            {
                Width = table.ActualWidth,
                Height = table.ActualHeight,
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString((string)table.Tag))
            };
            Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, Canvas.GetLeft(table));
            Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, Canvas.GetTop(table));
            Canvas.SetZIndex(rectangle, Canvas.GetZIndex(table));
            canvas.Children.Add(rectangle);
        }
        return canvas;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

`Convert` method is called only once at the beginning of application. Interesting that if I replace `return canvas` with `return value` it works like without converter, like it skip code before return.
Why converter doesn't work? What can I do?

Comment: "`return value` works like without converter". Obviously, because you return the input value and just ignore the new Canvas.

Comment: If you return value or workAreaCanvas nothing obviously changes because you made no changes to workAreaCanvas.

Comment: @Clemens But why it's not working, when I return new canvas? It updates only at the beginning of app.

Comment: You never explained what "not working" means exactly. Do you get any exception?

Comment: @Clemens When I create new table, move it, make other actions on `Canvas`, all this is not appearing in thumbnail - it's just empty. I don't get any exceptions.

Comment: @Pavieł Kraskoŭski It updates only when WorkArea.Content property changes (assuming that it implements INotifyPropertyChanged). You should probably make navigator the same way you did Workarea instead of using converters.

Comment: I'm also not sure if creating a Visual in a binding converter is a good idea (at least I've never seen it before), but you'll have to take care that the returned Canvas gets its layout done. Call its `Measure` and `Arrange` methods before returning it from the converter.